# Sorting by tags in the SO user page

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, sorting

In the user page searching questions and answers are very difficult.  If we had tag sorting that would make it easier to find the questions and answers that I've participated in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already exists: if you scroll down the user page, you'll see a list of tags:

> [image: Tag list]

Clicking on them will take you to a search results page that will you only questions and answers from that user for that specific tag.

If you want to further refine it, just add `is:question` to the search query just see questions and `is:answer` to just see answers.

Comment: off topic and out of mere curiosity, may I inquire why you deleted your answer in the c.SE discussion? I thought it made a good point and was wondering whether you were just tired of the discussion (which is a perfectly fine reason to withdraw an answer), or whether something came up that made you change your mind.

Comment: Ah, I think I see why now - the question in question was deleted.

Comment: @Pekka I realized that I didn't answer the question, as I was more interested in pointing out the hypocrisy of it instead of addressing its content due to my own annoyance with the situation.